# Is there a way to delete Single Files while having Multiple Input Files that are not Uploaded but previewed with File Reader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

When i remove the Images from the Preview(it is not Uploaded into the DB), it still is in there as a File and gets Uploaded. My Code literally removes the Image from the Frontend but it still gets Uploaded and i could not find a Way to delete the File i wanted to delete, and some even said it is not possible since FileReader is read-only! Now is there a Way to work around that or do i have to delete my Code and Start new?

I have read on several Websites that it is not possible to do it and then they showed a completely new Code. But i want to find a Way that it is possible to bypass this.

Here is my Code:

JS:

```
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;


            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {

                    $('<div class="previewdeleter position-relative" data-item-id-div="input.files[i].length" style="height:200px;width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative !important;">' +
                        '<img alt="" src='+event.target.result+' style="height:200px;width: 100%; display: inline-block;">' +
                        '<div class="position-absolute" style="top: 0;right: 0;">' +
                        '<img src="/x.png" class="image-deletepreview" style="height: 20px; display: inline-block;"></div></div>')
                        .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);


                    $('.image-deletepreview').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var deletepreview = $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                        console.log(deletepreview);

                    });

                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i],);
            }

        }


    };
```

MY HTML:

```
              <input value="" type="file" id="images" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
                <div id="previewHolder" data-item-id-div="input.files[i].length" multiple="" class="previewdeleter position-relative">
                    <div class="position-absolute delete-image">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Files that i wanted to delete are not deletable because they are Superglobals and should not be changed. So basically FileReader is read-only and access to the Files Input is denied!

There is currently not a Way i could find to delete the IMG before Upload in Laravel.

You can use a Preview with Upload then deleting the Preview will not be an issue.